# How to configure Network Interface in vxworks-cert-6.6 without using ifLib

Tags: networkx, vxworks

I am working on Kontron board with Vxworks-cert-6.6 RTOS in it. 
My current goal is to bring-up the **Network Interface** in it, and set a static IP address and a netmask for that interface.

As of now, I know 2 ways to achieve my requirement (to set a static IP address):

1. by providing **ead** bootline parameter, specifying IP address and netmask for boot interface.
2. by using ifLib network interface library.

The first method I cannot opt for the reason, after deployment end-user cannot change every time the **ead** bootline parameter for IP address to set and compile the whole bootrom and deploy back the device.

And, the second method is not permitted for me to use because for the reason, the Vxworks-cert package I am using doesn't come with ifLib library in it.

So above said both the methods are not feasible in my case. Even I have thought of a 3rd method to change bootline parameter during runtime and reboot. But this method is also not feasible for the main reason, the Kontron board I am using doesn't support NVRAM, and hence the bootline parameter I have changed during runtime doesn't withstand power-off/on cycles and new desired IP address will not be set.

Can anyone suggest me a method to achieve this; if any reference links it will be more helpful. Thank you in advance for all your helps.

Comment: So with "doesn't come with ifLib" you mean that the function is not available at runtime? If it is just not available at compiletime you might try getting a pointer to the functions using symLib by accessing the VxWorks symbol table.

Comment: Hi Lukas Thomsen, thank you very much for the reply. ifLib is not available at all, neither runtime nor compile time. The **INCLUDE_NETWRS_IFLIB** include itself isn't available.

Comment: And about symLib, can you please provide some more information or a link to reference. Because I am still exploring the stuffs in VxWorks.

Comment: On the VxWorks shell run the following command `lkup "ifAddrSet"`. This searches the symbol table for functions. If it doesn't show anything then you'll have no chance with using `ifLib` either. Let me know if `lkup` shows something and if it does I can provide some code to help you.

Comment: I ran the command `lkup "ifAddrSet"` and got `value = 0x0`

`-> lkup "ifAddrSet" `

` value = 0 = 0x0 `

`-> `

I guess, ifLib isn't available right ? Do I have any hope?

Comment: You're right ifLib is not included in your kernel. Under that conditions my idea will not work ... sorry.

Comment: @LukasThomsen, newbie question, How do you call a function once you have located it in symbol table? for e.g.                                                          
    -> lkup "sysClkRateGet"
    sysClkRateGet             0x10012380 text'

Comment: @LukasThomsen, thank you so much for your help. I have one small question here, is it possible to override the IP address which is set in **ead** parameter in Bootrom after VxWorks image loads up. I have seen include kernel config **TSTACK_IFCONFIG_1** is enabled and provided value **"ifname gei0","devname gei0","gateway 198.254.0.1","inet 198.254.0.100"**. But this parameter doesn't override the **ead** IP address I have set in boot parameter. Can you please point me what I am missing in between.

Comment: To directly call a function from the symbol table create a small C tool defining a function pointer to the function you want to call. Assign the value from the symbol table to the function pointer and call it (search for "function pointer c" in google and you'll find some more help).

Comment: Have you tried using command `bootChange` ?

Comment: @Lukas Thomsen, yes I thought of changing boot parameter using `bootChange`, but the NVRAM requirement is not met on my hardware. So that option is not available for me too.